# Differential equation questions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am studying differential equations of order $1$ and $2$ and I had these questions on my mind:

**1.** Is it true that every differential equation has infinitely many solutions if there are no initial conditions specified?

**2.** Is it true or false that the solution of every $2$nd order differential equation always has $2$ independent constants?

Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: 1. yes, 2. at least for linear ODEs yes, although I believe it holds more generally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but these statements are false. Consider the first order equation
$$f'(x)^2+f(x)^2=0.$$
It is easy to see that even without initial conditions, it must be that $f(x)=0$ identically. For your second order question, similarly consider
$$f''(x)^2+f'(x)^2+f(x)^2=0.$$

You should generally be wary about statements that claim to hold in all cases without many assumptions.

If you would like to include complex valued solutions then replace $f$ by $|f|$, $f'$ by $|f'|$, and so on.

Comment: so homogeneous differential equations have only one solution right?

Comment: For your first equation consider $f(x) = c*exp(-ix)$

Comment: and if we are talking about a 2nd order non homogeneous equation does the statement about 2 constants being independent stand?

Comment: @BadAtMaths Since this seems like a question for beginners I excluded the complex case. My answer extends to the complex case though, see the edit.

Comment: @LoveScience If you want to make any blanket statement about a class of equations having a certain number of solutions, then you're going to need to make more assumptions.

Comment: @LoveScience It depends if they're "linear" or not.

Linear DEs have as many constants as the order of the DE. This also implies infinite solutions.

There are no general rules for non-linear DE's, as the answer above showed off.

Comment: I think it's important to note that both of your examples come from implicit ODEs. If we have an explicit ODE in form $y' = f(y, x)$ then it's behaviour is much more controllable and is quite nice again.

Answer (score 0):

For linear DEs, those two facts are always true. That is great, because you'll be working with linear DEs 99% of the time.

Non-linear DE's do not behave as nicely, and may not adhere to those rules.